# How to make nginx redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect

How I can redirect all SSL requests to "https" folder? My frontend webserver is nginx.

For example:

https: //website.com/checkout.php should be redirected to https://website.com/https/checkout.php

Please help me with this question.

Answer (score 0):

in the server {} block

```
rewrite ^/checkout.php$  https://website.com/https/checkout.php permanent;
```

Comment: No, for all pages, not checkout only.

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ https://website.com/https$request_uri permanent;
}

location /https {
    // Whatever you normally do
}
```