# How to redirect http requests to https (nginx)

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, gitlab

There appear to be many questions and guides out there that instruct how to setup nginx to redirect http requests to https. Many are outdated, or just flat out wrong.

```
# MANAGED BY PUPPET

upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

# setup server with or without https depending on gitlab::gitlab_ssl variable
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name gitlab.localdomain;
  server_tokens off;
  root /nowhere;
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}
server {
  listen *:443 ssl default_server;
  server_name gitlab.localdomain;
  server_tokens off;
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  ssl                           on;
  ssl_certificate               /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key           /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
  ssl_protocols                 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers                   AES:HIGH:!ADH:!MDF;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers     on;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab puma)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl   on;

    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

I've restarted after every configuration change, and yet I still only get the 'Welcome to nginx' page when visiting `http://192.168.33.10`. whereas `https://192.168.33.10` works perfectly.

Why will nginx still not redirect http requests to https?

I've also tried the following configurations

```
  listen *:80;
  server_name <%= @fqdn %>;
  #root /nowhere; 
  #rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent; 
  #rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
  #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  #return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
  #return 301 http://192.168.33.10$request_uri;
  return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
```

The logs

```
tailf /var/log/nginx/access.log
192.168.33.1 - - [22/Oct/2013:03:41:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
192.168.33.1 - - [22/Oct/2013:03:44:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 133 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"

tailf /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.lob
2013/10/22 02:29:14 [crit] 27226#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: gitlab.localdomain, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket:/", host: "192.168.33.10"
```

**Resources**
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
[How to make nginx redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/208310/how-to-make-nginx-redirect)
[How to force or redirect to SSL in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx)
[nginx ssl redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/335684/nginx-ssl-redirect)
[Nginx & Https Redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/258120/nginx-https-redirection)
https://www.tinywp.in/301-redirect-wordpress/
[How to force or redirect to SSL in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx)

Comment: Can you show the config as it appears AFTER puppet deploys it? And more to the point, are you even deploying one for 192.168.33.1 at all?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've updated the question with the actual config after the puppet run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've identified the problem.

I had an entry in /etc/hosts that was misconfigured

```
127.0.0.1 gitlab.localdomain gitlab
```

As soon as I changed it to the following, https redirects started working

```
192.168.33.10 gitlab.localdomain gitlab
```

So in conclusion, this is the working syntax.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name gitlab.localdomain;
  server_tokens off;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;


}
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name gitlab.localdomain;
  server_tokens off;
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;
  ssl                           on;
  ssl_certificate               /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key           /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
  ssl_protocols                 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers                   AES:HIGH:!ADH:!MDF;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers     on;
…
```

*Note*
The redirect only works when calling the url by name, it does not redirect if navigating to the ip.

Answer (score 4):

2 things ion how to ensure http-to-https-redirects

- in your HTTPS - section, enable [HSTS-Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) _> this will ensure your browser send future requests in HTTPS only

  ```
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
  ```
- in your http-section: you could either `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;` (fastest approach) or rewrite (slower)

  ```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  ```

  }

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, return 301 is one of the options that I have tried with no luck. The user is simply presented the 'welcome to nginx' screen