# Redirect everything to https in Nginx

Tags: nginx

How to redirect every vhost to https but without duplicating configuration. I have 4 websites on the same vps running Nginx and I want to redirect everything to https.

Comment: Each redirect needs the site name, so you have to duplicate at least some of the config. You can use include for some parts.

Comment: not true @Tim see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this...

Redirect ALL requests to https 
[In catch-all server examples the strange name “_” can be seen](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/www-301_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/www-301_error.log;

        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Redirect specific domain names

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com *.example.com example.org *.example.org;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/www-301_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/www-301_error.log;

        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Comment: Similar answer https://serverfault.com/a/547748/200560

Comment: I prefer not to use the default server for this. I return an error status code so that only requests for configured domains are serviced. This is a solution, and there's nothing wrong with it, but it's not one I'd use personally.

Comment: Oh I agree, I 444 anyone hitting things like the IP Address directly, etc.

Comment: What is this underscore in server name ?

Comment: catch all, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: I would suggest using the second option, naming URLs, rather than the catchall.